# refer to map via. maps() action in python/ pylonshq

Tags: python, pylons

I just started to learn python, and i'm totally new and n00b. Normally i work with php. 
I choose to use this framework: http://pylonshq.com/

I have created an map called ajax in my controller map. 
now i just need my "htaccees" file to find the ajax map.

I want the file to go into the map /ajax/ where the file ajax_load.py is.

Right now, it looks like below. But i can't make it work :/

> map.connect('/ajax/{action}/', controller='ajax.ajax_load')

I hope someone can help me !

Comment: "I hope someone can help me !" does without saying.  Please remove this.  What helps more is to provide the exact error message or problem you're seeing.  "i can't make it work :/" isn't helpful and doesn't describe your problem.

Comment: "I hope someone can help me ! " Means what your are reading. Don't make it more complex than it is. ;) - I found a solutio, just don't use maps in the controller map. - anyway thx for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution :

http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/configuration/

this is how it works->
$ paster controller ajax/ajax_load